# Get return value from shinyalert

Tags: r, shiny

I'd like to return the user's choice (Confirm or cancel).  I can't seem to get it.

```
    shinyalert(
      title = "Are you sure you want to clear the data?",
      callbackR = function(x) {
      global$response <- x
    },
    imageHeight = "50%",
    size = "s",
    type = "input",
    showCancelButton = TRUE,
    confirmButtonCol = '#DD6B55',
    confirmButtonText = 'Yes, clear it!'
    )
    print(global$response)
    print (input$shinyalert)
    
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Works fine.  Try this

```
library(shinyalert)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    actionButton("btn", "Click me")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    global <- reactiveValues()
    observeEvent(input$btn, {
      # Show a simple modal
      # shinyalert(title = "You did it!", type = "success")
      shinyalert(
        title = "Are you sure you want to clear the data?",
        callbackR = function(x) {
          global$response <- x
        },
        imageHeight = "50%",
        size = "s",
        type = "input",
        showCancelButton = TRUE,
        confirmButtonCol = '#DD6B55',
        confirmButtonText = 'Yes, clear it!'
      )
      
    })
    observe({
      print(global$response)
      print(input$shinyalert)
    })
  }
)
```